# Python list values updated while appended new values, old values lost

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am running a script that extracts data into dictionaries, it creates new parameters with the old ones and then it has to append the new parameters to a list.

The loop goes well, every time I print parameters, it updates the values correctly and creates a new value, new url, everything fine.

The issue comes when I append parameters to the image_data_list. It does not add the new dictionary to the list, but it transform every value in the list into the new one, so I get lists of 200 equal dictionaries when I need a list of different dictionaries that I get in every iteration.

```
image_data_list = []
status = True
index = 1
sd.click_image()

while status:
    try:
        all_urls = sd.extract_images()
        parameters = sd.get_parameters(parameters_)
        for url in all_urls:
            parameters["url"] = url
            parameters["index"] = index
            print(parameters)
            image_data_list.append(parameters)
        print(image_data_list)
        index += 1

    except TimeoutException:
        status = False
        print("Ending Execution due to Timeout Exception")
        break
```

How con I avoid this type of results:

```
[{'age': 'adult', 'gender': 'female', 'ethnicity': 'latino', 'title': ' brown eyes', 'url': 'image_url.jpg', 'index': 4},
{'age': 'adult', 'gender': 'female', 'ethnicity': 'latino', 'title': ' brown eyes', 'url': 'image_url.jpg', 'index': 4},
{'age': 'adult', 'gender': 'female', 'ethnicity': 'latino', 'title': ' brown eyes', 'url': 'image_url.jpg', 'index': 4},
{'age': 'adult', 'gender': 'female', 'ethnicity': 'latino', 'title': ' brown eyes', 'url': 'image_url.jpg', 'index': 4},
{'age': 'adult', 'gender': 'female', 'ethnicity': 'latino', 'title': ' brown eyes', 'url': 'image_url.jpg', 'index': 4},
{'age': 'adult', 'gender': 'female', 'ethnicity': 'latino', 'title': ' brown eyes', 'url': 'image_url.jpg', 'index': 4}]
```

And get something like:

```
[{'age': 'adult', 'gender': 'female', 'ethnicity': 'latino', 'title': ' blue lips', 'url': 'image_url_1.jpg', 'index': 1},
    {'age': 'adult', 'gender': 'female', 'ethnicity': 'latino', 'title': ' brown eyes', 'url': 'image_url_2.jpg', 'index': 2},
    {'age': 'adult', 'gender': 'female', 'ethnicity': 'latino', 'title': ' caramel', 'url': 'image_url_3.jpg', 'index': 3}]
```

The final result must be a list of dictionaries with all different values per iteration, every new gets appended but old ones should not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u could try this,see if it's work

```
import copy
image_data_list = []
status = True
index = 1
sd.click_image()

while status:
    try:
        all_urls = sd.extract_images()
        parameters = sd.get_parameters(parameters_)
        for url in all_urls:
            copyed_parameters = copy.deepcopy(parameters)
            copyed_parameters["url"] = url
            copyed_parameters["index"] = index
            image_data_list.append(copyed_parameters)
        index += 1

    except TimeoutException:
        status = False
        print("Ending Execution due to Timeout Exception")
        break
```